# Requisição Ajax, retonando array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou com dificuldade em pegar a array que estou enviando via Ajax, eu sei que ela está enviando todos os índices, mas estou com duvida em como vou receber e tratar a leitura dessa array no documento "gravar_btn.php", coloquei um código de exemplo e vou deixar a imagem de como está a página no navegador abaixo.
O objetivo é coletar as informações contidas na array e gravá-las no banco de dados.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
function atualiza() {
    var indices = [];

    //Pega os indices
    $('#cotacoes thead tr th').each(function () {
        indices.push($(this).text());
    });

    var arrayItens = [];

    //Pecorre todos os produtos
    $('#cotacoes tbody tr').each(function (index) {

        var obj = {};

        //Controle o objeto
        $(this).find('td').each(function (index) {
            obj[indices[index]] = $(this).text();
        });

        //Adiciona no arrray de objetos
        arrayItens.push(obj);
    });

    //Mostra dados pegos no console
    console.log(arrayItens);

    //Envia para o php
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gravar_btn.php",
        data: arrayItens,
        success: function(result){
            alert("Envio realizado com sucesso!");
        },
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<table id="cotacoes"> <!-- Tabela de exemplo -->
  <thead>
    <tr> 
      <th>Nome</th> 
      <th>Telefone</th> 
      <th>Endereço</th> 
      <th>Cep</th> 
   </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td>Ricardo</td> 
      <td>(21) 9999-9999</td> 
      <td>Rua Dois, casa 3.</td> 
      <td>99999-999</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>Silvia</td> 
      <td>(21) 9999-9999</td> 
      <td>Rua Um, casa 2.</td> 
      <td>99999-999</td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>

<form action="gravar_btn.php" method="POST">
<button class="button is-block  is-small" onclick="atualiza();">Enviar</button>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Não sei o que você está chamando de "tratar", mas seja o que for que precise fazer com os dados vindos do ajax, faça dentro do callback de "success".

Comment: preciso gravar as informações da array no banco de dados, mas não sou muito familiarizado com javascript, dentro do callback "success" eu consigo montar um loop pra ler a array e gravar os dados no banco? Nesse caso a url: "gravar_btn.php" ficaria em branco?

Comment: Essa parte você faz no php, não no js

Comment: Então, a parte do loop que vai gravar as informações no banco eu já fiz, só não estou conseguindo pegar a array no documento "gravar_btn.php", como seria o código que recebe a array no "gravar_btn.php"? (Estou começando agora nessa área de desenvolvimento, por isso sou meio leigo pra algumas coisa kkk)

Comment: De um print_r($_POST) no seu php para ver os dados recebidos.

Comment: Consegui resolver com suas dicas, muito obrigado pela ajuda! :)